# Lua: RegEx to Pattern

Tags: string, lua, string-matching, gsub, lua-patterns

Simple problem...I need to turn this RegEx pattern...

```
"\[\"([0-9]+)\"\]"
```

into a Lua pattern.

I am doing this to replace a bunch ["X"] lines with just [X] in a string where X is any number from -∞ or +∞...so that's about the only limitation. I need to port this to Lua patterns so I can use it in String.gsub.

```
Find: "\[\"([0-9]+)\"\]"
```

Also, how do I just remove the " " around the number? I need a pattern for that. If someone could help me out, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try like this.

```
> f = "foo [\"12\"] bar"
> x = string.gsub(f, "%[\"(%d+)\"%]", "[%1]")
> print(f)
foo ["12"] bar
> print(x)
foo [12] bar
```

`\d` which matches any digits would be represented as `%d` in [lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub).

Comment: I'd probably have suggested `'%["(%d+)"%]'` instead to avoid the confusion of needing to escape the embedded double quotes.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. As to Etan's suggestion, I see the reasoning, but I like " better and the escaping is not a huge problem for me. :) Thanks guys.